# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.wsgi'

Tags: python, django, heroku, wsgi

I am trying to upload a django app in heroku but when test locally using heroku local it gives me an error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stockDataProject.wsgi'

I understand that my Procfile does not target to the relevent WSGI file but I do not know how to do it

My app is organized in the following: 
DjangoAPP

```
----- projectEnvironment
----- stockDataProject
---------- manage.py
---------- requirements.txt
---------- stockDataProject
-------------- urls.py
-------------- wsgi.py
-------------- settings.py
----- db.sqlite3
----- git
----- gitignore
----- Procfile
```

and my Procfile:`web: gunicorn stockDataProject.wsgi --log-file -`

howcnI solve this issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have everything nested one level too much. The Procfile should be inside the outer `stockDataProject` directory, which should be the root of your git repo.

Comment: ok got it.. it thought it was a path issue in the Procfile thx you It is now working